# Modal Dialog in React

Tags: reactjs, modal-dialog, state, onchange, default-value

I am working in React application and wants to open a modal dialog on a button click. I am using materialize css in my application. I can open the modal dialog fine but have some issues with the input box inside the modal dialog. My intention is to pass a value through properties to the sub component inside the modal dailog box and show that value in the input box. This works fine for the first time, as I am setting the defaultValue property of the input.

Next time if I send a new value through properties to modal dialog it wont update the input box value inside the sub component but keeps showing the default value set or the user changed value . I tried to use the value instead of defaultValue, but it asks for onChange event as well and use the state of the component to set the value of the input box.

The problem with this is when I use the onChange event of input box and do the setState, it closes the modal dialog if I do not do setState then the modal dialog box is readonly.

How should I circumvent this to update the input box all the time when the value in parent changes and that should update the modal dialog box as well.

This is how I am using a sub component with input box inside the modal dialog

```
<input  type="text"
id={"min_" + this.props.index + "_inputId"}
key={"min_" + this.props.index + "_inputKey"}>
defaultValue={this.props.Value}                                               
onBlur={function (event) { that.props.onBlur(event, this.props.index) }                      
</input>
```

Comment: Best way to create modal is react portal. Portal renders outside of root so other css style do not affect it. here is the link https://reactjs.org/docs/portals.html

Answer (score 0):

You may use value property instead of defaultValue it works fine once check it and you can open the Modal like `<Modal isOpen ={this.state.isModalOpen} autoFocus={true}> </Modal>`. By using the isModalOpen property you can open the modal. if you use setState also it won't close until you set the value of isModalOpen false.